# Inserting into selected item of sub array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My data is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e57db66c6bb04eb902589a2"
    },
    "name": "temp1",
    "sub_arr": [{
        "_id_": "53",
        "_text": "Different ministries & states are working together",
        "labels": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    }, {
        "_text": "We need to work together, take small yet important measures to ensure self-protection.",
        "_id_": "54",
        "labels": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }]
}
```

I can get the item of the subarray that I need as follows:

```
db.mycollection.find({"name":"temp1"}, {"sub_arr":{"$elemMatch": {"_id_": "54"}}})
```

Now I would like to insert into that item another sub array as follows:

```
db.mycollection.find({"name":"temp1"}, {"sub_arr":{"$elemMatch": {"_id_": "54"}}}).upsert.updateOne({'ins_labels': [{"id": "a1", "label": "A"}]})
```

However it does not work. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.mycollection.update({"name":"temp1","sub_arr._id_":"54"},{"$set":{"sub_arr.$.ins_labels":[{"id": "a1", "label": "A"}]}})
```

mongo maintains the position of the array list when array is part of the query.